# How can I use C# to apply a patch to a database?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a batch file that contains commands to restore a database using patches from a folder. I want to make a GUI application which can execute SQL commands but rather than applying all of the patches in the folder.

I currently have the following sqlcmd in the batch file:

```
sqlcmd -E -S(local) -i "c:\temp\MergedPatchFiles.sql"
```

The patches in the folder are numbered - I need a way to find the current patch number of the database and the number of patches in the folder and use a for each loop to apply only the patches that are required.

How can I execute an 'apply patch' SQL command using C# on a specified database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

- Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to execute `sqlcmd` directly (or even the batch file directly...)
- Load the SQL up and execute it using [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286484.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Load the sql file into a string and use the SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might run into issues if your file has GO statements, so you can use [this approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx):

```
string scriptDirectory = "c:\\temp\\sqltest\\";
string sqlConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;" + 
            "Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=(local)";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(scriptDirectory);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.sql");
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fi.FullName);
    string script = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *I need a way to find the current patch number of the database...*

To begin with, how are you storing in the database what revision database you are currently at? I've come across 3 different schemes for keeping track of revisions:

1. a DDL audit table,
2. a table with 1 row that has a version number,
3. "nothing" - where you have to guess based on what columns, tables, views and stored procs which revision of the database this is.

The audit table can be as simple as a column for the patch number, a column for when it was completed, or more complicated [like this example](https://serverfault.com/questions/100114/sql-server-2000-database-table-dissappeared-what-are-the-possible-reasons/100127#100127).

The version table is sometimes the most I can get away with at companies I'm working for. At the minimum, it just needs 2 or 3 columns and 1 row. The structure of that table should never change so that version 51 of the application can open a database made by version 2.

Most companies I've worked for have no scheme to track what version the database is at other than detective work by figuring out that table_Q was added in version 17, but view_P was added in version 19 and taken out in version 21, so this database is probably version 19 or 20.

One of my friends was talking to me about [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) last week, and he claimed there was some patching scheme in it that can detect patches dropped into a directory, determine if they've been applied already and process the ones that haven't been. I'll see if I can get better details from him.